Parse markdown heading in CKeditor
I am using extra markdown for heading like this
#### Title {.classname}
Inside CKEditor it displayed as is.
Title {.classname}
How to make it to be displayed with class applied and hidden {.classname}?
Like this:**
Title

What did you expect? CKeditor is not a markdown editor.
